# iOS iCloud Containers: are these two containers the same?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, icloud

**What I did**

I built an iOS 7 app, using default options for anything iCloud related. In Xcode 6, I now see that in my project, on my main target, under capabilities, under iCloud - it shows that my app does not use the default container. If I select "Use default container" it changes the URL.

```
iOS 7 format - "ABC123ABCD.com.companyname.product"
iOS 8 default - "iCloud.com.companyname.product"
```

**Questions**

- If I change to the iOS 8 default, will users loose their documents, OR - are these effectively the same directory?
- Why the change? What's the difference? Any clarity around this change would be really helpful.

Comment: save yourself an incredible amount of time and just change to using parse.com  :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not the same containers. Existing data from the first container will not be accessible in the second container.

Existing containers of your live apps are still accessible, but as of Xocde 6.0.1 it appears that it is required for new containers to begin with iCloud.

Why this has changed probably has to do with Cloud Kit, but why Apple have not told us developers about this change or how to handle it appropriately is beyond me, and absolutely ludicrous I think. This change is fundamental, causes lots of headaches and has not been implemented in beta versions of Xcode 6.

Comment: To clarify: if I try to keep the same container (the non iCloud one) and update my app using Xcode 6, will this be allowed/will my app continue to function correctly??

Comment: If your old container still exists, and if it's selectable in the Capabilities section (under iCloud, appearing grey) then yes. Some of my old containers that I used for testing have turned red and are no longer available, but the ones I had setup for live apps are still working fine.